# Neutral wire going into panel has ~120 volts on it

Tags: electrical

I know there are threads about open neutrals, but wasn't sure if this is a different case with it being in my panel rather than outlet or switch.  Can I assume there is an open neutral somewhere or could it be something else?  Where should I start looking?  Would the break or loose connection be between the panel and first outlet or could it be anywhere in the circuit?  We noticed this when swapping a breaker in the panel.

Comment: When you see this 120VAC on a neutral wire in your panel is this with that particular wire detached from the neutral bus bar in the panel?

Comment: Yes, it's detached from bus bar.  When making contact with that neutral wire to the bus bar, there is a spark.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a neutral wire removed from the neutral bus bar in your panel it is possible to see 120VAC on that wire if the circuit breaker for that circuit is turned on and there is a load connected to the circuit and load device is also turned on.

The disconnected neutral means that no return current is flowing in that circuit but with a connected load it is possible to see the 120VAC through the load when when measured.

This picture will help you see how you can measure the 120VAC on the neutral wire:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Working as intended.   The ordinary loads on the circuit are "pulling up" the disconencted neutral up to 120V.  You are preventing electrons from returning to their source, so they are queueing up waiting.  The voltage pressure behind this is 120V.

The loads aren't reducing the voltage any, because of Ohm's Law.

E = I x R

Voltage drop across the load (E) = current being flowed (I)  x effective resistance of load (R)

Because you have disconnected it, current flowing is 0.

E = 0 x R

E=0 obviously.   Since voltage *drop* is 0, you see full line voltage there.

Answer (score 0):

The neutral is the return for the power if disconnected it will rise to the voltage supplied. When you see a spark that is powering the load that is energised. It could be a phantom voltage induced from running in close proximity to other live conductors but phantom voltages don't usually spark when grounded. I would find the breaker that is powering the ungrounded conductor normally black wire and turn that off and you probably won't see a spark but possibly still a phantom voltage until the wire is back on the buss. The voltage would be normal with power and a load on the circuit some place.